# all the body moves except the head

Tags: animation, modifiers, particles, edit-mode, add-on

The head I created in the nomad program (iPad)

I made the bone but the head that I made doesn't movie. How do I solve that?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE. What do you mean by "movie"? like a movie video? or do you mean "move" or "moving"

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie 
the head of the body didn't move when I applied the armature to it,
I can move everything accept the head, how can I make it one body?

Comment: @moonboots
dear, the file is more than 30mb it's around 76mb how can I share it?

Comment: use another platform, like workupload for example

Comment: @moonboots 
this is the Link: https://workupload.com/file/awVevaJusbW
could you plz tell me what the issue

Answer (score 0):

Create a vertex group that you call *f8ry.004* (like the bone that is supposed to control the head) and assign all the head vertices to this vertex group (by the way, the mesh is much too dense, you should simplify it):

[image]

Second file: I'm not sure what you've done, first thing remove the head vertices from all groups:

[image]

Now the head bone is called *f8ry.005*, so assign the head vertices to this vertex group:

[image]

Comment: could u plz tell me how to simplify the dense?

Comment: You could select the head mesh and X > Limited Dissolve for example

Comment: dear @moonboots
after i did what u say, not all the head I can move it just the front of it , I will upload a picture to see it
link:  https://ibb.co/ph7xZNG

Comment: Please share your file again

Comment: ok dear 
https://workupload.com/file/fu8PB6Vry6Y

Comment: I've edited my answer

Comment: I did and it's fixed it, all my thankful to you Mr @moonboots thank you

Comment: Dear, if i want to import it as FBX they didn't import it 
do u have solve for that ?
https://www.top4top.me/do.php?imgf=top4top_me327b79a54a950.png

Comment: your link doesn't work and i'm not sure what's the problem with the fbx, maybe ask a new question?

Comment: dear i can't put new question they ban me